# null is not an object (evaluating 'snapshot.forEach')

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to subscribe to a query on firestore but I'm getting an error when I add a filter.

this works just fine

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (dbChats && currentUser?.uid) {
      const unsubscribe = dbChats
        .orderBy('createdAt')
        .limit(100)
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          const chats = firebaseLooper(querySnapshot);

          setChats(chats);
        });
      return unsubscribe;
    }
  }, [dbChats]);
```

but this doesn't

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (dbChats && currentUser?.uid) {
      const unsubscribe = dbChats
        .where('participants', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid)
        .orderBy('createdAt')
        .limit(100)
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          const chats = firebaseLooper(querySnapshot);

          setChats(chats);
        });
      return unsubscribe;
    }
  }, [dbChats]);
```

whenever I add
`where('participants', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid)`

It throws the error

```
null is not an object (evaluating 'snapshot.forEach')
```

Note that this also works

```js
dbChats.where('participants', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid).get()
```

Comment: Afaik the snapshot should never be null. The only thing I can think of is that it might be returning an error, but you haven't supplied any error handling to onSnapshot (it's the second param). Or there's something funny going on in `firebaseLooper`, but you haven't shown us that.

Comment: thanks for the insights on the onError param.
I was missing an index `The query requires an index.`
If you'd like to make an answer out of this I'll accept it as valid

Comment: Cool cool. Btw every new query will require a new index in firestore. It won't do anything without an index.

Comment: Nice, I'm fairly new to firestore and didn't know that thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `snapshot` is null because you haven't supplied any error handling and the query is throwing an error. Simply supply an error handler as a second param to `onSnapshot`.

Answer (score 0):

windowsill is correct. Once I properly supplied error handling I received the error from firebase `[Error: [firestore/failed-precondition] The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/...`

In my case I needed to add an index.

Change this:

```
firestore().collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        var cities = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            cities.push(doc.data().name);
        });
        console.log("Current cities in CA: ", cities.join(", "));
});
```

To something like this:

```
firestore().collection('cities').where('state', '==', 'CA')
  .onSnapshot({
    error: (e) => console.error(e),
    next: (querySnapshot) => {
      var cities = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        cities.push(doc.data().name);
      });
      console.log('Current cities in CA: ', cities.join(', '));
  }
});
```